# How to highlight four random selections from a column?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to randomly highlight (change the cell colour) of four cells in the first Excel column. It is important the selections highlighted are only cells containing data as the size of the data set will vary.

The highlighted selections needs to be un-highlighted when the macro is run again to generate four new selections.

I have tried to brute force this with functions (`RAND`-`RANK`-`XLOOKUP`), but the outcome is messy and doesn't react to different sizes of data.

Highlighting the cells in a color is the goal, conditional formatting could be suitable.

Four random cells from the first column of the Excel sheet is the target (cells only containing data).

Answer (score 1):

### Using Conditional Formatting

Let's say you have data in column A. For example 16 rows like this:

[image]

You could use the `COUNT()` function to calculate the number of cells with content in column A in cell D1 :

```
=COUNT(A:A)
```

[image]

And then you could calculate the position of the cells you want to highlight with

```
=RANDBETWEEN(1,$D$1)
```

[image]

Then you can create a helper column to check if a cell should be highlighted.

Formula in G2 : `=IFERROR(MATCH(CELL("row",A2)-1,$D$2:$D$5,0)>0,FALSE)`
The idea behind this function is simply to check if the row of the data point corresponds with one of the random positions we have.

[image]

Finally, you would use a formula to define your conditional formatting by applying it to Column A and using `=$G2` as the formula.

[image]

Note that:

- The highlighing will reset everytime you change a cell provided that you have "Automatic calculations" turned ON.
- There is a possibility that 2 or more of the random positions are the same, so you'll need to recalculate if that's an issue.